# qt opengl shader texture coordinates

Tags: qt, opengl, shader

I use OpenGL shader for apply median filter to image. Input image I copy to in_fbo buffer. All work fine.

```
QGLFramebufferObject *in_fbo, *out_fbo;
painter.begin(in_fbo); //Copy QImage to  QGLFramebufferObject
painter.drawImage(0,0,image_in,0,0,width,height);
painter.end();

out_fbo->bind();
glViewport( 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight );
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();

glOrtho( 0.0, nWidth, 0.0, nHeight, -1.0, 1.0 );

glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity( );

glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

out_fbo->drawTexture( QPointF(0.0,0.0), in_fbo->texture( ), GL_TEXTURE_2D );
```

But in shader code I need divide position of vertex by width and height of image, because texture coordinates are normalized to a range between 0 and 1.

How correctly calculate texture coordinates?

```
//vertex shader
varying vec2 pos;
void main( void )
{
    pos = gl_Vertex.xy;
    gl_Position = ftransform( );
}
//fragment shader
#extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : enable

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform int imgWidth;
uniform int imgHeight;
uniform int len;
varying vec2 pos;

#define MAX_LEN (100)

void main(){
    float v[ MAX_LEN ];

    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
         vec2 posi = pos + float(i);
         posi.x = posi.x / float( imgWidth );
         posi.y = posi.y / float( imgHeight );
         v[i] = texture2D(texture0, posi).r;
    }
    //
    //.... Calculating new value
    //

    gl_FragColor = vec4( m, m, m, 1.0 );
}
```

---

Before I did it in OpenFrameworks. But shader for texture in OF does not work for texture in Qt. I suppose because OF create textures with textureTarget = GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB. Now the result of applying shader above isn't correct. It isn't identical with result of the old shader (there are few pixels with different colors). I don't know how modify shader above :(.

Old shaders:

```
//vertex
#version 120
#extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : enable

void main() {
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
}


//fragment
#version 120
#extension GL_ARB_texture_rectangle : enable

uniform sampler2D texture0;
uniform int len; 

void main(){
    vec2 pos = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;

    pos.x = int( pos.x );       
    pos.y = int( pos.y );

    float v[ MAX_LEN ];

    for (int i=0; i<len; i++) {
        vec2 posi = pos +  i;       
        posi.x = int( posi.x + 0.5 ) + 0.5;
        posi.y = int( posi.y + 0.5 ) + 0.5;
        v[i] = texture2D(texture0, posi).r;
    }
    //
    //.... Calculating new value
    //       
    gl_FragColor = vec4( m, m, m, 1.0 );
}
```

OpenGL code from OpenFrameworks lib

```
texData.width = w;
texData.height = h;

texData.tex_w = w;
texData.tex_h = h;
texData.textureTarget = GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_ARB;

texData.bFlipTexture = true;
texData.glType = GL_RGBA;

// create & setup FBO
glGenFramebuffersEXT(1, &fbo);
glBindFramebufferEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, fbo);

// Create the render buffer for depth
glGenRenderbuffersEXT(1, &depthBuffer);
glBindRenderbufferEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, depthBuffer);
glRenderbufferStorageEXT(GL_RENDERBUFFER_EXT, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, texData.tex_w, texData.tex_h);

// create & setup texture
glGenTextures(1, (GLuint *)(&texData.textureID));   // could be more then one, but for now, just one
glBindTexture(texData.textureTarget, (GLuint)(texData.textureID));
glTexParameterf(texData.textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(texData.textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameterf(texData.textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf(texData.textureTarget, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexImage2D(texData.textureTarget, 0, texData.glType, texData.tex_w, texData.tex_h, 0, texData.glType, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_MODULATE);

// attach it to the FBO so we can render to it
glFramebufferTexture2DEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0_EXT, texData.textureTarget, (GLuint)texData.textureID, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not think you actually want to use the texture's dimensions to do this. From the sounds of things this is a simple fullscreen image filter and you really just want fragment coordinates mapped into the range [**0.0**,**1.0**]. If this is the case, then `gl_FragCoord.xy / viewport.xy`, where viewport is a 2D uniform that defines the width and height of your viewport ought to work for your texture coordinates (in the fragment shader).

`vec2 texCoord = vec2 (transformed_pos.x, transformed_pos.y) / transformed_pos.w * vec2 (0.5, 0.5) + vec2 (1.0, 1.0)` may also work using the same principle -- clip-space coordinates transformed into NDC and then mapped to texture-space. This approach will not properly account for texel centers (`(0.5, 0.5)` rather than `(0.0, 0.0)`), however and can present problems when texture filtering is enabled and the wrap mode is not `GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE`.

Comment: Thank you for answer, gl_FragCoord.xy / viewport.xy is the same as pos.x = pos.x / imgWidth :) I update my question...